# Multiple Conditional JQuery Contains Search

Tags: jquery

I am modifying an Instant JQuery Search for use on a sharepoint list with multiple columns.

I have almost got this working right, but having trouble with using AND conditions as well as OR conditions.

the search box looks like so,

User1 OR User2,Customer

this is how I would like the users to search.. meaning they can search for User1 OR User2 AND Customer.  What this should produce is pretty straight forward, and this is how I think it should look.  But it's not doing the AND operator on Customer.

```
tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('User1'),tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('User2'):tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Customer')
```

below is my javascript:

```
 var txt = $("input.search").val().split(',');
         var str = "";
         var strnot = "";
         if (txt)
         {
             for(var i=0;i<txt.length;i++) {
                var txt2 = txt[i].split('OR');
                if (txt2.length > 1) {
                    for (var j=0;j<txt2.length;j++) {
                        if (j==0) {
                            str += "tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('"+txt2[j].toString().trim() +"')";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (txt2[j].length > 0) {
                                str += ",tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('"+txt2[j].toString().trim() + "')";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (txt[i].length > 0) {
                        if (i == 0)
                            str += "tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('"+txt[i].toString().trim() +"')";
                        else
                            str += ":tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('"+txt[i].toString().trim() +"')";
                    }
                }
             }
             $("#temp").html(str);

             //$("#WebPartWPQ2").find(str).hide();     
             //$("#WebPartWPQ2").find(str).show();    

            $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not("+str+")").hide();     
            $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover"+str+"").show();    
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
        }
```

Comment: Try jQuery filter() http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: try : tr.ms-itmhover:contains('User1'):contains('User2')